# How to combine the multi line output of a command to one line?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have the below output from a command in a bash shell:

```
username
country
```

But I would like to modify the printed output to be:

```
username - country
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something like:

```
$ seq 6 | awk '{printf "%s", sep $0; sep = " - "}; END {if (NR) print ""}'
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6
```

Or:

```
$ seq 6 | paste -d ' - \n' - /dev/null /dev/null -
1 - 2
3 - 4
5 - 6
```

Or:

```
$ seq 5 | sed '$!N;s/\n/ - /'
1 - 2
3 - 4
5
```

If it's just a two line output, you can also do:

```
$ seq 2 | { IFS= read -r a; IFS= read -r b; printf '%s\n' "$a - $b"; }
1 - 2
```

Which in shells like `bash` where `read` and `printf` are builtin saves having to execute a separate command. In `bash`, you can save spawning an extra process to do that processing by setting the `lastpipe` option (only in non-interactive shell instances).

Answer (score 2):

`tr` can transform a character into another:

```
echo "username
country
town" | tr '\n' ' '
```

output:

```
username country town
```

use `tr -d` to replace a character (newline) by nothing:

```
echo "username
country
town" | tr -d '\n'
```

output:

```
usernamecountrytown
```

but if you want to replace newline by several characters, `tr` is not enough (I have nevertheless spoke about it because it's a very simple command).

But it can be done with `sed`:

```
echo "username
country
town" | sed ":a; N; s/\n/ - /; ta;"
```

output:

```
username - country - town
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipe it to this:

```
sed -z 's|\n| - |'
```

That uses GNU `sed` to replace the newline with `-`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk 'ORS=" - "{print $0}' filename|awk '{gsub(/- $/,"",$0);print }'
```

output

```
username - country
```